# Is there any way to revive my Sim?

Tags: the-sims-4

My sim died  by freezing. Making an ambrosia is quite tough. Is there any cheat code to revive my sim?

Answer (score 12):

Use the cheat `traits.remove_trait Ghost_Frozen`.

---

You can use the cheat `traits.remove_trait X`, where `X` is the trait that caused your Sim to die:

> you must use the exact type of death cheat to reverse it.
>   Use the simology panel if you're unsure.

See [this page](https://www.carls-sims-4-guide.com/death/ghosts.php) for more types of death and their trait names, and [this page](https://sims-online.com/sims-4-seasons-cheats-death-gardening/) for more info on using cheats.